# Iterating selected items in Windows App Store Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light

I know this is a long one, but please bear with me.

I have created a windows app store program very similar to Laurent Bugnion's "MyFriends" program in the MVVM light samples using the MVVM light framework.

In his program he uses the SelectedItem property of the gridview to keep track of which item is the selected item.

The problem is, I give the user the ability to select multiple items on the GridView and then operate on them using a button on the App Bar. For this SelectedItem will not work.

Does anyone know how to make this work with a multiselect GridView? I have tried the IsSelected property of the GridViewItem based on some articles on WPF, but this doesn't seem to work. The SelectedTimesheets getter always come back empty when called. Here is what I have so far:

MainPage.xaml (bound to a MainViewModel with a child TimesheetViewModel observable collection):

```
<GridView 
    x:Name="itemGridView"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Timesheets}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TimesheetTemplate}" 
    Margin="10"
    Grid.Column="0"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    helpers:ItemClickCommand.Command="{Binding NavigateTimesheetCommand}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.738,0.55"  >
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

</GridView>
```

MainViewModel (cut down from full code):

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        Timesheets = new ObservableCollection<TimesheetViewModel>();
        ExecuteRefreshCommand();

    }

    public ObservableCollection<TimesheetViewModel> Timesheets
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TimesheetViewModel> SelectedTimesheets
    {
        get { return Timesheets.Where(o => o.IsSelected); }
    }

    private async void ExecuteRefreshCommand()
    {
        var timesheets = await _dataService.GetTimesheets("domain\\user");

        if (timesheets != null)
        {
            Timesheets.Clear();

            foreach (var timesheet in timesheets)
            {
                Timesheets.Add(new TimesheetViewModel(timesheet));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

TimesheetViewModel:

```
public class TimesheetViewModel: ViewModelBase
{

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public Timesheet Model
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public TimesheetViewModel(Timesheet model)
    {
        Model = model;

    }
}
```

If I set the IsSelected property manually, the SelectedTimesheets lambda works, so the problem is somewhere in the binding of the XAML to the IsSelected property.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jerry-Nixon-MSFT's answer spurred me on to rethink it (thanks to him) and I came up with the following solution.

Firstly I changed the XAML to accept a new helper method **SelectionChangedCommand.Command** and bound it to a **RelayCommand** called **SelectionChangedCommand** in my view model

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<GridView 
    x:Name="itemGridView"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Timesheets}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TimesheetTemplate}" 
    Margin="10"
    Grid.Column="0"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    helpers:ItemClickCommand.Command="{Binding NavigateTimesheetCommand}" 
    helpers:SelectionChangedCommand.Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}
    "RenderTransformOrigin="0.738,0.55"  >
</GridView>
```

I then added a **SelectionChangedCommand** helper class under my helpers namespace to translate the **SelectionChanged** event into an **ICommand**

```
namespace TimesheetManager.Helpers
{
    public class SelectionChangedCommand
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(SelectionChangedCommand), new PropertyMetadata(null, 
            OnCommandPropertyChanged));

        public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject d, ICommand value)
        {
            d.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static ICommand GetCommand(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (ICommand)d.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }

        private static void OnCommandPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = d as ListViewBase;

            if (control != null)
                control.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
        }

        private static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = sender as ListViewBase;
            var command = GetCommand(control);

            if (command != null && command.CanExecute(e))
                command.Execute(e);

        }
    }

}
```

This binds the **SelectionChanged** event of any control which inherits from **ListViewBase** (our gridview) to a method called **OnSelectionChanged**. **OnSelectionChanged** subsequently passes the **SelectionChangedEventArgs** from the control to the **RelayCommand** binding in the XAML.

Finally in **MainViewModel**, I process the **RelayCommand** and set the **IsSelected** flag:

**MainViewModel:**

```
private RelayCommand<object> _selectionChangedCommand;

/// <summary>
/// Gets the SelectionChangedCommand.
/// </summary>
public RelayCommand<object> SelectionChangedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _selectionChangedCommand ?? (_selectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<object>
        ((param) => ExecuteSelectionChangedCommand(param)));
    }
}

private void ExecuteSelectionChangedCommand(object sender)
{
    var x = sender as SelectionChangedEventArgs;

    foreach (var item in x.AddedItems)
            ((TimesheetViewModel)item).IsSelected = true;

    foreach (var item in x.RemovedItems)
            ((TimesheetViewModel)item).IsSelected = false;

}
```

I know there is a fair amount of casting going on, but we are limited to object by the **ICommand** interface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this was posted quite a while ago, but I'm wondering about a couple of things: 1) Is there not a way to implement this as part of the GridView control if you create a custom gridview that inherits from the GridView? 2) When the SelectionCommand is triggered in the viewmodel, it always seems to be triggered but the total number of selected items is incorrect if you use the method posted by JerryNixon-MSFT. It always seems that the selection is one behind. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Sure, I know what you mean. Too bad this isn't automagic, but it isn't. The solution involves a simple custom `GridView` that inherits from `GridView`. Nothing too crazy, that is, if you let it sink in. Here's the code, I just tested it:

Here's your XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <local:MyGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                      BindableSelectedItems="{Binding Selected}" />
    <local:MyGridView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Selected}" />
</Grid>
```

Here's your view model (super-simplified):

```
public class ViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<string> m_Items
        = new ObservableCollection<string>(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => x.ToString()));
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get { return m_Items; } }

    ObservableCollection<object> m_Selected = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    public ObservableCollection<object> Selected { get { return m_Selected; } }
}
```

And here's your custom gridview:

```
public class MyGridView : GridView
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> BindableSelectedItems
    {
        get { return GetValue(BindableSelectedItemsProperty) as ObservableCollection<object>; }
        set { SetValue(BindableSelectedItemsProperty, value as ObservableCollection<object>); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BindableSelectedItems",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(MyGridView),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, (s, e) =>
        {
            (s as MyGridView).SelectionChanged -= (s as MyGridView).MyGridView_SelectionChanged;
            (s as MyGridView).SelectionChanged += (s as MyGridView).MyGridView_SelectionChanged;
        }));
    void MyGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BindableSelectedItems == null)
            return;
        foreach (var item in BindableSelectedItems.Where(x => !this.SelectedItems.Contains(x)).ToArray())
            BindableSelectedItems.Remove(item);
        foreach (var item in this.SelectedItems.Where(x => !BindableSelectedItems.Contains(x)))
            BindableSelectedItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Just one new property `BindableSelectedItems`.

Best of luck!

Comment: Note the ObservableCollection<object> for Selected in the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I'll give this a go. I'm looking to see if I can extract the code here out to a helper method and will post back.

Comment: Just added an answer. Reworked it to use a helper class. Thanks.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT Glad I found this solution as all other appear overly complicated just to achieve this but is there a way to use/extend the above to pre-select items in the listview/gridview based on the binded collection i.e. Selected? Thanks.